# Verify only Login credentials from DB

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

session_start();
include("connection.php");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die("Could not connect to database");
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Login") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE name='"
            . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['name'])
            . "'AND password='" 
            . md5(md5($_POST['name']) . $_POST['password'])
            . "'LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        header("Location: http://www.ccm.net/forum/");
    } else {
        $error = "We could not find a user with that email and password. Please try again.";
    }
}    
?>
```

I have the above codes just to login an user.I have a table with the username and password already.I dont want to create a signup button,just a login button as the password will be their 'id' itself.I am able to connect to db.

Please help me, as after login I'm taken to a blank page.

Comment: `md5(md5($_POST['name']) .$_POST['password'])` Whats that?

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not as secure as one would hope plus that you don't even escape all the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

First off all: You are vulnerable to sql injections using this code. Please use parametrized queries so you don't forget to escape values you use in your queries.

```
$mysqli = new Mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
$mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM EmployeeTable WHERE name = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1');
$mysqli->bind_param('ss', $name, $password);
$mysqli->execute();
$result = $mysqli->fetch_array();
```

You should also not use `md5` for password hashing. Use the built in `password_*` functions.

[`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) can be used to hash passwords like so:

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

This also applies what is called a [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to strengthen the hash against dictionary attacks.

When you want to verify passwords use can use [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the password against the stored hash like so:

```
$is_correct = password_verify($password, $hash);
```

Using these methods you are very unlikely to mess anything up.

A direct answer to your question could be either: `if ($_POST['submit'] == "Login")` or `if($row)`. I would use `count()` to check the number of results found like so: `if(count($row) > 0)`.

Comment: You're missing a `?` after `password = `

Answer (score 0):

At a guess without seeing the rest of the HTML, it is probably not satisfying the if $_POST["submit"] statement:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Login") {
```

and just ends the script as there is no else option. Perhaps check that your form is POST, Name of button is actually "submit" and its value is "Login"